# "Xcopy" error when create and run UWP app with Template 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, template10

I am having issues with template 10. 
I have installed Template 10.  I then created a new project and choose Blank or Hamburger/Minimal. After that, I followed this [guide](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Welcome-%7C-Blank-Template). But when I run my project, I get the following error:

> "xcopy
>   "C:\Users\phams.nuget\packages\Template10\1.1.11\build\uap10.0....\lib\uap10.0"
>   "C:\Users\phams\Desktop\WindowsApp1\WindowsApp1\obj\x86\Debug\"
>   /e/s/y/q" exited with code 9009.

(I use Visual Studio 2015 update 3 on Windows 10)

Comment: 1. try to restart your vs. 2. try to clean the project and build again.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT :thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**issues solved** I have uninstalled the Template 10 and re-installed it, then F5 & cheers

> Visual studio 2015:
>
> TOOLS -> Extensions and Updates... -> Installed, choose Template 10 Template Pack -> **Uninstall**.
>
> TOOLS -> Extensions and Updates... ->Online, Ctrl+E & enter "Template 10 Template Pack" ->**Download**.
>
> **Restart** your VS and **Create** a project with Template 10. Join!